# How do I adjust the width of a grid column?

Tags: tables, spacing

I've tried looking up the code and couldn't find something that allows me to adjust the width of a column. I want to make the width larger (in the vertical direction). This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | p{2cm} |}
     \hline
      Problem & Points \\ \hline
      1 &   /4 \\ \hline
      2  &  /4 \\ \hline
      3  &  /4 \\
     \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: What do you mean by width in the vertical direction? Do you mean the *height*? Or do you mean the *horizontal* width? Or something more exotic...? Please adjust your code so that it compiles to demonstrate the problem. This will help people to help you.

Comment: You can increase the vertical height via `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<factor>}`.

Comment: See [Column and row padding in tables](http://goo.gl/X3kPH).